# how to skip format validation in my case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model User with an attribute "guest" (BOOLEAN)
I want to skip format validation on email if user.guest == true or user.guest == nil,

tried

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /^(\S+)@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.)([a-z]{2,4})(\.?)([a-z]{0,4})+$/i
validates :email, format: { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX } unless :guest?
```

but now even when user have guest == false or guest == nil validation is still skipping

What could be wrong?

another common validation works good:

```
validates :email, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } unless :guest?
```

Comment: i just needed to change syntax into "..., unless: :guest?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /^(\S+)@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.)([a-z]{2,4})(\.?)([a-z]{0,4})+$/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},  unless: :guest?
```

Comment: right syntax is "..., unless: :guest?" see answer on [my common question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846850/how-does-rails-helper-method-attribute-changed-works-in-rails-3-2-15)