# How does rails helper method :attribute_changed? works in Rails 3.2.15?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my situation
I need: to generate user confirmation code if user's email have changed

i have
    model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  after_update :generate_confirm_code if :email_changed?
...
  def generate_confirm_code
    self.confirmation_code = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.first(8)
    self.confirmed = false
  end

  def update_last_visit
    self.last_visit = Time.now.utc
    save
  end
...
end
```

also have a method :update_last_visit in application_controller which saves user last visit time

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
...
  def update_last_visit
    current_user.update_last_visit if current_user
  end
...
end
```

here is the problem starts:
every time i reload the page my confirmation code changes, even when i did not change the email. Seems like updating last_visit also changes confirmation_code  but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have the syntax slightly wrong on your `after_update` macro. As you have it now, the `if :email_changed?` is actually just a modifier on whether or not to run the `after_update` macro when loading the User class. I.e. it's the same as `puts "hi" if :some_condition?` (the `if` is non an input to the `puts` method here).

What you want is to pass an `:if` option to the `after_update` macro, like this:

```
after_update :generate_confirm_code, if: :email_changed?
```

Notice that the `if:` is now rooted in the options hash of the `after_update` macro.

See also, the [Rails Guide on ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-%3aif-and-%3aunless-with-a-symbol).

Comment: this also solved my second problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797041/how-to-skip-format-validation-in-my-case

Comment: Cool, glad I nailed a 2-for :). You may want to delete that other question then? Or supply the answer and accept it to clear it out.